# wp_update_post using post_name

Tags: wp-update-post

Can I update posts using the `post_name` (slug) instead of the `ID`, as I don't have a list of the ID's, but I do have the list of the slugs and the corresponding changes for each one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$post = get_page_by_path( 'the_slug', OBJECT, 'post_type' ) ;
$id = $post->ID;
```

Then you an update post using this ID.
Note: Untested, may contain syntax error.